# Negative parameter in MVC url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In the MVC routing engine, a url of "/MyController/Action/-123/type" and a routing rule of:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "AddRemoveRequestee",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{requestId}/{someOtherData}",
           defaults: new { },
           constraints: new { controller = "MyController", action = @"[Aa]ction", requestId = @"-?\d+"});
```

MVC will call the Action(int requestId, string someOtherData) method of the controller, but it will pass 123 as the value of requestId rather than correct value of -123.

Is there a more elegant way handle this issue than:

```
    //HACK:Fix to handle when MVC annoyingly makes negative values in the url positive
    private int FixNegativeParameter(int id, int paramPos=-1)
    {
        //HACK:Check the raw URL against what MVC passed in.
        string rawUrl = this.Request.RawUrl;
        var urlParts = rawUrl.Split(@"/?".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (paramPos >= 0)
            //Parameter is specified explicitly
            return urlParts[paramPos] == "-" + id ? -id:id;
        //Position not specified.  Looks for any instance of the negative of id
        //HACK:  Not totally reliable if url has multiple int arguments
        return urlParts.Any(up => ("-" + id) == up) ? -id : id;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Action(int requestId, int profileId)
    {
        requestId = FixNegativeParameter(requestId);
        <remainder of code that accepts negative ids as valid>
    }
```

Possibly a way to change this default behavior?

Comment: I'm unable to re-produce the issue in MVC version 5. I'm getting the expected `-123` as the value.

Comment: Interesting.   I'm using MVC 4, due to corporate limitations.   I wonder if this is just an MVC 4 bug?

Answer (score 0):

You could try URL encoding the - sign.

```
/MyController/Action/%2D123/type
```

I think the issue is that routing will toss it out as being a delimiter character. If you [URL encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) `-`, it should pass through as a value.

Comment: I've tried this.  The parser still removes the negative.

Answer (score 0):

ok, looking again...it just looks like your route isn't complete - you're missing a bracket in your action...

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { },
            constraints: new { controller = "Home", action = @"([Ii])ndex", id = @"-?\d+"}
       );
```

I get -ve values...

Just update yours similarly.

Comment: Not that it is more of a hack than what I'm already doing, but that is just trading one inelegant solution for another.

Comment: @SvdSinner - try my new answer - I looked closer at your code

Comment: Good catch, but that bit of code with was just a generic bit I substituted to keep from posting any internal info on the web.   The actual route in my app is correct.  I'll update the example code to be syntactically similar to actual.